# What happens when an application disconnects right after sending a query to update records?

Tags: database, mongodb

I have thousands of records to update in Mongo. I am using updateMany(filter, update) to update all those documents in one go.

My question is, once request is sent to mongo server, my connection resets. Will the update operation happen on the mongo server?

I have a Spring boot application where I send this request from.

Comment: *"Will it happen?"* - Is actually a little broad without specifics. In most cases it probably will, and it really all depends on whether there was a network error or not when sent from the client, or even when committing between servers depending on the write concern used. ( More direct response about that part in the first linked answer ). The additional *"wrinkle"* here is that if you use Transactions, then ultimately nothing would be committed without the issuing appliciation doing a specific **commit**. Which it cannot since your application failed or whatever. I suggest reading both.

Comment: And I suppose there is also "retryable writes", but again it's a little unlclear if you mean *"...connection resets.."* in the sense of a **small interuption** or where you can basically just presume the application or it's access to the database is non existant for an extended period of time. I'd read the resources on that. But if you think you have a much more specific case to present. Then by all means ***be specific***

Comment: You'll need to make time. Point is that it's not a Yes or No question. And certainly not on the very broad strokes you presented. That's why the existing resources may help you decide what exactly you are asking or looking for.

Comment: Sure. LIves down the street. There's only about 50 of us here anyway :)